# Can I see if my cursor is over a zone?

Tags: jquery

I mean, I'd like to check (on a .hover function) if my cursor pointer is into/outo a zone.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/X48XS/) is an example :

## HTML

```
<ul class="menuLeft">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>    
    <li>3</li>    
</ul>
```

## jQuery

```
$('.menuLeft > li').hover(
    function() {
        alert("i'm into UL");
    },
    function() {
        //if the cursor, when I leave a li, is into the ul, print "IN", else "OUT"
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to achieve. If you want to trigger actions when the mouse enters/leaves `<ul>` why not use `$('ul.menuleft').hover(...)`?

Comment: Because I need to trigger singles <li>, not the whole <ul> :)

Comment: In that case, your code is already doing that. Perhaps you can elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve and what the difficulty is?

Comment: What are you asking?  Your code appears to do what you want right now.

Comment: No!!!! If I leave a <li> I should enter in another <li>, or (what I'M ASKING) just leave the <ul>. This is what I'm looking for...but -2 doesnt justify this imo! Mah...

Comment: It's still hard to understand. So, you basically want 2 different things to be tracked. 1-moving from LI to LI. 2-moving out of the UL altogether. Or do you only care about the UL? In which case you just need a different selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I fully understand the question. It looks like you want "in" to be triggered when an LI is entered and "out" to be triggered when you leave the UL altogether. But since "in" can just as easily be triggered by entering the UL instead of an LI, why not do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/429zG/

```
var $menuLeft = $('ul.menuLeft');
$menuLeft.hover(
    function() {
        $menuLeft.addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
        $menuLeft.removeClass('hovered');
    }
);
```

(`hovered` class just has `background-color: green`)

Trying to track success of your code with alerts is going to be tricky for mouse events, which is why I just add or remove a class instead.

If you want to track BOTH the LI hover and a UL hover, you just need to bind two different event handlers.

http://jsfiddle.net/429zG/1/

(code not pasted; all it does is bind another event with an LI selector that changes each LI's background color on hover)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare mouse position to the position and width/height of ul

```
function(e) {
    var ul =  $('#someUL');
    var offset = ul.offset();
    var width = ul.width();
    var height = ul.height();
    if(e.pageX >= offset.left && e.pageX <= offset.left + width && e.pageY >= offset.top &&       e.pageY <= offset.top + height) {
     console.log('IN');
    } else {
      console.log('OUT');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confusing question, but check out [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). They are intended to handle nested objects.

Comment: [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) used by OP in the question is already a shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: My bad :( was under the impression that it's mouseover and mouseout